# Export in Python

Tags: python, node.js

Появился такой вопрос: Можно ли использовать и есть ли вообще такая вещь, как export в Python ? Я хочу экспортировать функцию из одного файла в другой. В node js я бы использовал `export const function` и `import { function }`. Могу ли я сделать также в Python ?

Comment: в python можно  писать модули и импортировать...

Comment: В python по сути все функции и глобальные объекты модуля уже экспортируются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто импортировать необходимый файл.
Например если файлы лежат в одном каталоге.

file2.py наш файл с функцией:

```py
def pr():
    print("Hello!")
```

file.py сюда мы импортируем функцию:

```
import file2

file2.pr()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ